# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin.Forms PCL Android debugging - Blank exception, no Callstack, no Locals

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have created a new Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) project in Visual Studio 2015 and modified App.cs to always throw an exception:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        throw new Exception("Exception");
}
```

When I debug it in Visual Studio Emulator for Android, or in physical Android device the debugger stops on the exception, but that is all. No exception details are available, no call stack, no locals, nothing:
[image]

However, when I debug it in Windows Phone emulator, everything works as it should be:
[image]

**Is that normal behavior? How to get exception details, call stack, locals... etc?**

Any ideas?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 RTM, Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings

Check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions."